# Binary encoding of comma separated string column

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm trying to do a binary transformation of a comma separated string column in a data frame that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                 mystring = c("test1,test2", "test2,test3", "test1"))

print(df)

  id    mystring
1  1 test1,test2
2  2 test2,test3
3  3       test1
```

I want to achieve a binary transformation like:

```
df_result <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), 
                        test1 = c(1,0,1), 
                        test2 = c(1,1,0), 
                        test3 = c(0,1,0))

print(df_result)

  id test1 test2 test3
1  1     1     1     0
2  2     0     1     1
3  3     1     0     0
```

Comment: First step: split the strings.

Comment: Try `cbind(df[1],  mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df$mystring), ",")))`

Comment: great.. that's exactly what I was looking for.. thanks @akrun

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387859/dummify-character-column-and-find-unique-values/42388860#42388860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df[1], mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df$mystring), ",")))
```